# UIPickerView + Accessibility = crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, uipickerview, uiaccessibility

my custom UIPickerView crashes when accessibility is on. I'm using following code (simplified; yes, I want/need to use subviews for the component view here).

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *columnView;

    if (!view)
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];        
        columnView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50.f, 30)];
        [view addSubview:columnView];
    }
    else {
        columnView = [view subviews][0];
    }

    columnView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];

    }

    return view;
}
```

Stack:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1ffb16, 0x325a6c64 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x325a6c64 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x24ef8b48 CoreFoundation`-[NSException raise] + 8
    frame #2: 0x25bdbdda Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 262
    frame #3: 0x25b42ea6 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 202
    frame #4: 0x292840ec AccessibilityUtilities`-[NSObject(UIAccessibilitySafeCategory) safeValueForKey:] + 104
    frame #5: 0x2360c112 UIKit`-[UIAccessibilityPickerComponent accessibilityTraits] + 358
    frame #6: 0x235e76c8 UIKit`__68-[UIApplicationAccessibility _findContainerAccessibleElement:first:]_block_invoke + 76
    frame #7: 0x2f73dc1c UIAccessibility`-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityEnumerateContainerElementsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 276
    frame #8: 0x235e7602 UIKit`-[UIApplicationAccessibility _findContainerAccessibleElement:first:] + 330
    frame #9: 0x235e7d76 UIKit`-[UIApplicationAccessibility _accessibilityElementFirst:last:forFocus:] + 490
    frame #10: 0x235e80ba UIKit`-[UIApplicationAccessibility _accessibilityFirstElementForFocus] + 30
    frame #11: 0x235ea8ec UIKit`-[UIApplicationAccessibility accessibilityAttributeValue:] + 352
    frame #12: 0x2f7355a6 UIAccessibility`_copyAttributeValueCallback + 122
    frame #13: 0x2920ceec AXRuntime`_AXXMIGCopyAttributeValue + 116
    frame #14: 0x29208ea4 AXRuntime`_XCopyAttributeValue + 300
    frame #15: 0x29212bb6 AXRuntime`mshMIGPerform + 242
    frame #16: 0x24ebedaa CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
    frame #17: 0x24ebed46 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
    frame #18: 0x24ebd348 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1608
    frame #19: 0x24e0b620 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    frame #20: 0x24e0b432 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #21: 0x2c1b90a8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 136
    frame #22: 0x283f5808 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
  * frame #23: 0x000db7f4 ds`main(argc=1, argv=0x001eab08) + 116 at main.m:14
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/22697817/479478. No one has an explanation yet :(

Comment: I am now using a workaround, maybe it will help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29128745/479478.